# Can you edit monitor disposition with a macro

Tags: multiple-monitors, macros, windows-11

I have a setup with 3 monitors and I use it in 2 different dispositions.

1: Screen 3 alone, screens 2/1 duplicated

2: Screen 2/3 duplicated, Screen 1 deactivated

I can't find a way to set theses 2 profiles on a hotkey or a batch file to avoid going through parameters each time. Anyone knows a tool/batch to make this out ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following free third-party utilities for saving
and restoring monitor setup:

- [MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
- [DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK)